# Select a Cell in a Storyboard created UITableView and programmatically create a UITableView and display and populate it with data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have created a tier of three UITableViews using Storyboard and am able to move from the first to the second and then to the third.  I now want to create a fourth UITableView programmatically.  By selecting a Cell in the third UITableView a fourth tier UITableView must be created and displayed so that I can populate it with data.  Please help. Thanks very much. Herewith included is the portion of the code that I want to execute :

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.grapes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

     if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqual: @"Grape variety"]) {

    //create the navigation controller and add the controllers view
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    [self.window addSubview:[self.navigationController view]];

    //check if the display viewcontroller exists, otherwise create it
    if(self.displayViewController == nil) {
        ViewController *inputView = [[ViewController alloc] init];
        self.displayViewController = inputView;
    }

    //push the display viewcontroller into the navigation view controller stack
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.displayViewController animated:

}
```

The "-(void)tableView ... is from the TableView created using Storyboard and the last portion of the code is the TableView I want to create programmatically.

If I excecute the code the newly created TableView corrupts the one created in the Storyboard and it doesn't display the one I want to create programmatically, somehow one must be able to change the priority of the display and get the latest created one to be the one that is active

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a drill down approach where the segue on the storyboard effectively loops back on itself (see image below):

[image: Loop back segue]

You could then provide an abstracted datasource and delegate implementation to make the view controller as light of logic as possible. Eg

```
@implementation ArrayDataSource

- (id)itemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    return items[(NSUInteger)indexPath.row];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView 
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return items.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView 
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    id cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier
                                              forIndexPath:indexPath];
    id item = [self itemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    configureCellBlock(cell,item);
    return cell;
}

@end
```

You could then configure it according to which tableview you are using by keeping a track of where you are:

```
void (^configureCell)(PhotoCell*, Photo*) = ^(PhotoCell* cell, Photo* photo) {
   cell.label.text = photo.name;
};
photosArrayDataSource = [[ArrayDataSource alloc] initWithItems:photos
                                                cellIdentifier:PhotoCellIdentifier
                                            configureCellBlock:configureCell];
self.tableView.dataSource = photosArrayDataSource;
```